# How to set blocks and text on image and be full responsive

Tags: css, image, text, flexbox

I am making a website from PSD file using flexbox. I need to create blocks like below. I am wondering how to set this pictures by using img tag or set them as background-image to be full responsive? Also I don't know how to set text "Active users(34)" and "Products Used(658). I tried with position absolute and relative but in smaller resolution it runnning of image...

[image]

My code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.blocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.blocks__text {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
}

.blocks__text h1 {
  color: #fd634e;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.blocks__text h2 {
  color: #a2ca28;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.blocks__text p {
  color: #656e74;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.blocks__text img {
  padding: 10px;
}

.blocks__text a {
  color: #a2ca28;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.blocks__image {
  width: 67%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.blocks__bg1 {
  background-image: url('../images/fitnessFirst.png');
}


.blocks__image p {
  color: #f7614c;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.blocks__users {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 60%;
}

.blocks__users p span {
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .blocks__text {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .blocks__image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25em;
  }
}

.blocks2 {
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.blocks__bg2 {
  background-image: url('../images/yourBody.png');
}

.blocks__users2 {

}

.blocks__users2 p{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
                    <article class= 'blocks'>
                        <div class='blocks__text'>
                            <h1>IT'S ALL ABOUT</h1>
                            <h2>FITNESS FIRST</h2>
                            <img src='images/whiteShape.png'>
                            <p>Cras et dolor libero. Aenean luctus accumsan enim quis finibus. 
                                Sed id mattis leo. Nulla nulla turpis, 
                                condimentum eu felis eu, consequat volutpat orci.
                                Maecenas lacus justo, fermentum eu pulvinar quis, posuere vel velit.
                            </p>
                            <a href="#">Read More</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class='blocks__image blocks__bg1'>
                            <div class='blocks__users'>
                                <p>Active Users <span>(34)</span></p>
                                <img src="images/orangeShape.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>

                    <article class= 'blocks blocks2'>
                            <div class='blocks__image blocks__bg2'>
                                    <div class='blocks__users2'>
                                        <p>Products USed <span>(658)</span></p>
                                        <img src="images/orangeShape.png">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <div class='blocks__text'>
                                <h1>LOVE YOUR BODY</h1>
                                <h2>YOUR BODY</h2>
                                <img src='images/whiteShape.png'>
                                <p>Cras et dolor libero. Aenean luctus accumsan enim quis finibus. 
                                    Sed id mattis leo. Nulla nulla turpis, 
                                    condimentum eu felis eu, consequat volutpat orci.
                                    Maecenas lacus justo, fermentum eu pulvinar quis, posuere vel velit.
                                </p>
                                <a href="#">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                </div>
```

Any idea how to make the same height always for white block and green one ??
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class='blocks__image blocks__bg1'>
    <div class='blocks__users'>
       <img src="../images/fitnessFirst.png" alt=""/>
       <p>Active Users <span>(34)</span> <img src="images/orangeShape.png"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and set this style

```
.blocks__users {position: relative;}
.blocks__users p {position: absolute; bottom: 40px; right: 30px}
```

Comment: You saved me :)